# D8-9. How to store Layout Builder custom block content as config

Tags: configuration, drupal-8, drupal-9

I'm creating custom pages using Pages + Layout Builder. These layouts need to be stored in GIT as config files (`drush cex`). Currently, the layouts themselves are stored fine.

The main problem is that custom block contents are stored in the database and if someone clones the repository and applies changes using `drush cim`, they are missing the block contents.